# Why is my port not open despite having configured it in IPTABLES

Tags: iptables

I'm setting up split tunnel vpn on my raspberry and want to make sure no incoming traffic is accepted on my VPN-interface (tun0) except for on the port I explicitly open: 56292. I use iptables for this and despite it seeming right to me I cant seem to get through the firewall. I've tried from outside the network as well as from the localhost with:

```
cat < /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/56292
```

My `iptables -L -nv` looks like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 35680 packets, 6816K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
58  7392 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:56292
1    76 REJECT     all  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
        
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
         pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination  

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 141K packets, 26M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 9380 3625K ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            owner UID match 1001
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      tun0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            owner UID match 1001
83686   10M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      eth0   !192.168.2.50         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

TCPDUMP shows me this:

```
$ sudo tcpdump port 56292 -v -i tun0
tcpdump: listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
21:37:51.114955 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 17284, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 76)
    188.166.15.60.39516 > 10.18.108.196.56292: UDP, length 48
21:37:51.429340 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 47156, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    188.166.15.60.33732 > 10.18.108.196.56292: Flags [S], cksum 0xd85f (correct), seq 2422478710, win 29200, options [mss 1357,nop,nop,TS val 1736027970 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
21:37:51.429528 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    10.18.108.196.56292 > 188.166.15.60.33732: Flags [R.], cksum 0xc592 (correct), seq 0, ack 2422478711, win 0, length 0
```

Comment: Please review your INPUT chain as incoming traffic is filtered by that chain. Even if you configured the OUTPUT chain by accident I don't see an explicit configuration for the port your mention.

Comment: It accidently got removed when I quoted the block to code. Adding it now

Comment: use `tcpdump` to see if packages are making their way through.

Comment: I did but from my readout it seems like it comes through and gets a ACK in return

Answer (score 0):

You may not have that port open on either your router or a firewall on the pc.

This may help if you are using Red Hat: https://superuser.com/questions/794104/how-to-permanently-disable-firewall-in-red-hat-linux